# Changing a divider with setDivider in a ListActivity without a custom ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, drawable, listactivity, divider

I can't seem to get a customized divider, using a Drawable I've defined, to work when using a `ListActivity` and not creating a custom `ListView`.  It almost seems like when the VM creates its own `ListView` for me, with the `ListActivity`, it uses a theme with the default divider provided; and if I try to provide one, no dividers appear in the `ListView` at all.

I know that I can create a custom `ListView` using XML and define android:divider on that `ListView`, and this does recognize my custom divider Drawable.  But I would prefer to just let the `ListActivity` create its own `ListView`, if I can figure out how to get my own divider working on it.

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
public class Categories extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final String[] OPTIONS = {
            "Hello",
            "Goodbye",
            "Good Morning",
            "Greetings",
            "Toodaloo"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, OPTIONS);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        PaintDrawable sage = new PaintDrawable(R.drawable.sage);
        lv.setDivider(sage);
        lv.setDividerHeight(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I figured it out.  The issue had nothing to do with the ListActivity generating a ListView for me.  It was in how I was defining the divider in Java code.

There are two ways that I see to define the divider (border between ListView rows) on a ListView that is automatically inflated from a ListActivity, if you want to define the color in XML:

Method 1:

In res/values/colors.xml, put the following:

```
<resources>
 <color name="sage">#cceebb</color>
</resources>
```

In your ListActivity-extending class, do this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
ColorDrawable sage = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.sage));
lv.setDivider(sage);
lv.setDividerHeight(1);
```

---

Method 2:

In res/values/colors.xml:

```
<resources>
 <drawable name="sage">#cceebb</drawable>
</resources>
```

And in your class that extends ListActivity:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
ColorDrawable sage = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.sage));
lv.setDivider(sage);
lv.setDividerHeight(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

**To set divider in listview programatically**:

These code put inside in your *.java* Class

```
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
   lv.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_divider));
   lv.setDividerHeight(1);
```

**Creating Drawable**: {res > drawable > **drawable_divider.xml**}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ececec"></solid>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
searchText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wordColorBlack));
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider2));
lv.setDividerHeight(2);
```