# increase the spacing between items in a List view in android

Tags: android, listview

I am generating a listview as follows:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, fileListS));
```

in which "row" is the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="14sp">
</TextView>
```

Is there an easy way to increase the spacing between the items lists in the generated listview?
If I was using a ListView instead of TextView I guess I could use:

```
 android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
```

But what can I do now that I use TextView?

Thanks,

TJ

Comment: android:padding="100dip"

Comment: padding just increases the size of each box in a listview, I want to increase the height of the divider that divides boxes in the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to change the thickness of the divider?

If so you could use a drawable similar the issues/solutions here

[Using a Drawable Divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979218/android-listview-divider)

[Maybe a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049069/android-changing-a-divider-with-setdivider-in-a-listactivity-without-a-custom-li)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  The second link worked nicely.